# Does there exist any non-contractible manifold with fixed point property?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Does there exist any non-trivial space (i.e not deformation retract onto a point) in $\mathbb R^n$ such that any continuous map from the space onto itself has a fixed point. I highly suspect that the quasi circle on $\mathbb R^2$ is an example. Yet I've not written down the (dirty) proof. But in this case all its homotpy groups are trivial. So if I assume my space as a manifold, then ***(QUESTION:)*** does this fixed point property force it to become a contractible manifold? I read somewhere that there exists a contractible compact manifold which does not satisfy this fixed point property. So does there exist any non-contractible manifold (compact) where this property follows? Or otherwise can anyone please provide an outline of how to prove that such a manifold is contractible?

Comment: There are many examples of orientable closed manifolds (hence not contractible since the top dimensional homology group is non zero) in that question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265743/closed-manifolds-with-the-fixed-point-property

Comment: @coudy Thanks, that's a nice source.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Take the space $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Its cohomology ring is given by $\mathbb{Z}[a]/a^3$, where $a$ has degree $2$. A map $f:\mathbb{CP}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^2$ induces a map on the second cohomology group with $f^*(a)=k a$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. From this you can compute the action on (co)homology on the other degrees. In degree zero it is the identity and on the fourth degree it is given by multiplying with $k^2$. Then the Lefschetz number of this map is seen to be $L(f)=k^2+k+1$. This number is never zero. A non-zero Lefschetz number implies a fixed point by the Lefschetz fixed point Theorem.

Comment: Wow!! Nice argument. I was trying to use Lefschetz fixed point theorem, but this one didn't come in my mind.

Comment: The same argument shows that $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ has the fixed point property for all $n$. Incidentally, this implies the fundamental theorem of algebra, because it implies that every complex matrix has an eigenvalue.

Comment: Hm, no, sorry, I thought I saw a cute way to only use $\mathbb{CP}^d$ for even $d$ but it doesn't work. Let me sketch the correct argument for completeness: you can use the Lefschetz fixed point theorem to prove that if $M$ is an $n \times n$ invertible complex matrix, then the map it induces on $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ has a fixed point, which says exactly that $M$ has an eigenvector. This proves the same statement for all matrices after possibly replacing $M$ with $M$ plus a suitable scalar multiple of the identity. I was hoping to only use $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ but this only proves the statement...

Comment: ...for odd-dimensional matrices, and there shouldn't be a way to get the conclusion for all matrices as a result (e.g. because over $\mathbb{R}$ it's true that odd-dimensional matrices must have real eigenvalues, but not even-dimensional matrices).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I believe that it's fixable. If you assume that M is invertible (which is fine, otherwise 0 is an eigenvector) then it induces a self-map that has to send $x \in H^2$ to $k x$. When $n$ is odd the above argument works; when $n$ is even, $x^{n-1}$ is sent to $k^{n-1} x^{n-1}$, but then the constraint that M induces an _orientation-preserving_ diffeomorphism (due to the complex structure) forces $k=1$, and so the Lefschetz number is $n$.

Comment: @Tyler: well, the Lefschetz number is always $n$ because $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is connected. I meant I wanted to use only the fact "$\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ has the fixed point property" as a black box.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Fair enough, sorry for the bother.

Comment: I think that quaternions projective space $\mathbb{H}P^n$ gives more examples. Regarding $\mathbb{C}P^{2n}$ there  is an alternative proof of FPP without using Lefschetz number as follows: If $f$ is  a  fixed point free map on  $\mathbb{C}P^{2n}$ then $f^{*}(\ell)$ is transverse to $\ell$ where $\ell$ is  the  tautological line  bundle. We consider both bundles $\ell$ and $f^{*}(\ell)$ as subbundles of the trivial $(n+1)$ dimensional bundle $\epsilon_{n+1}$.

Comment: This  shows that the  complement of  $\ell$ in $\epsilon_{n+1}$ is not  an irreducible  vector  bundle but it  contradicts to computation of charactersitic classes.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think your argument also shows that any self-map of $\mathbb{C}P^m$ has fixed points even when $m$ is odd.  In that case we can take $f([z])=[\overline{z}]$ and we find that $f^*(x)=-x$ in cohomology and the Lefschetz number is zero.   The fixed point set is $\mathbb{R}P^m$ which is nonempty but has Euler characteristic zero, consistent with the Lefschetz theorem.  A nice example!

Comment: @NeilStrickland  But  $\mathbb{C}P^m$, m odd,  does not have fixed point property. Moreover how does  my argument shows this implication? I doubt that the argument works for m odd.

Comment: @AliTaghavi you are right, I misunderstood slightly how your argument works.  In fact, I think that it gives exactly the same criterion as the Lefschetz theorem, and so does not tell us very much when $m$ is odd.

Answer (score 5):

Another nice example is $\mathbb RP^{2n}$. Here is a simple proof...

If $f:\mathbb RP^{2n} \to \mathbb RP^{2n}$ is a continuous function then look at the lift of the map $\bar{f} :S^{2n}\to S^{2n}$. A fixed point of $f$ is equivalent to a point $x\in S^{2n}$ s.t. $\bar{f}(x)=x \ or \ -x$. If such a point doesn't exist, then we can have a homotopy between Identitity and Antipodal map via $H(x,t)=cos(t)x+sin(t)\bar{f}(x)$.[This is well defined map from sphere to sphere]. But for even dimensional sphere antipodal map has degree $-1$. That's a contradiction.

Comment: This should also follow from the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, since $\Bbb{RP}^{2n}$ has the rational homology of a point. (Compact simplicial complexes whose homology is all torsion fall to the same argument.)